# Why is reduce returning a list instead of a single value?

Tags: python, reduce, functools

I was just exploring reduce, but I'm not understanding the whole systematic behind it. I do understand that reduce will most likely return a single value, but how does it work in this context?

```
    answer = reduce(lambda x, y: x[0]*x[1] * ([y[0] + y[1]]), [(2,6), (1, 2), (5, 6)])
```

Comment: It *is* returning a single value; that value is a list.

Comment: Because your `lambda` is returning a list, and the result of `reduce` will be the last return value of your `lambda`. (`2 * 6 * ([1 + 2])` results in `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`)

Comment: Your lambda expression creates a list from the outer brackets on the right side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[y[0] + y[1]]` is a list, so your lambda is multiplying an integer `x[0]*x[1]` by a list `([y[0] + y[1]])`, so you're getting another list as the result because:

```
>>> 5 * [6]
[6, 6, 6, 6, 6]
>>> 8 * [4,6]
[4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6, 4, 6]
```

---

As for why the result is `9 * [11]`:

```
>>> def thing(x, y):
...  print(x, y)
...  return x[0]*x[1] * ([y[0] + y[1]])
... 
>>> reduce(thing, [(2,6), (1, 2), (5, 6)])
1. (2, 6) (1, 2)
2. [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] (5, 6)
[11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]
```

1. `x == (2, 6)`, `y == (1, 2)` => `tmp1 == (2 * 6) * [1 + 2] == 12 * [3]`
2. The first argument is the accumulator, so `x` is now the list of 3's from the previous iteration. Per your formula, `result == (3 * 3) * [5 + 6] == 9 * [11]`

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. In my example, the return value is  [11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11]. Why? I don't understand, why the third value (5,6) is multiplied by nine...

Comment: @Guckinho First your lambda will be called with `x = (2, 6)` and `y = (1, 2)`. Next your lambda will be called with `x` being whatever the previous call returned and `y = (5, 6)`. Write it out on paper.

Comment: Thanks guys, I now understood it!

Comment: @Guckinho, also please see my edit for further explanation